# Is there a way to prevent Geb from returning null from void methods?

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

In a Spock Specification any line in **expect:** or **then:** block is evaluated and asserted as `boolean`, unless it has signature with return type `void`.

I've noticed that there is something odd going on for methods declared as `void` on any class inheriting from `Navigator` (for example `Page` or `Module` classes).

Let say we have such example:

```
class NavigationSpec extends GebSpec {

    def 'Collections page has a right header'() {

        when:
            to CollectionsPage

        then:
            hasHeaderText('Collections')
    }
}
```

The `hasHeaderText()` method is defined within `CollectionsPage` class as follows:

```
class CollectionsPage extends Page {

    static url = 'movies/collections'

    void hasHeaderText(String expectedText) {
        assert true
    }
}
```

On purpose I'm just asserting `true` over there so it should never fail. Even though it fails with an error:

```
Condition not satisfied:

hasHeaderText('Collections')
|
null
```

How and why a `void` method call result is evaluated as `null`?

I know how to 'fix it'. It's enough to declare the method return type as `boolean` and return `true`. This is ugly though as following all the asserts otherwise unnecessary `return true` has to be added like:

```
boolean hasHeaderText(String expectedText) {
    assert header.text() == expectedText
    return true
}
```

This causes only noise though. Is there any way to prevent Geb from returning `null` from `void` methods?

I'm, of course, aware that this specific case could go like:

```
boolean hasHeaderText(String expectedText) {
    header.text() == expectedText`
}
```

This doesn't explain the oddity of lost `void` return type, not to mention we loose meaningful assert failure message with such approach.

Answer (score 4):

It's part of the Groovy language that every method returns a value. This allows any method to be used in expressions or as lambdas.

All methods that are declared `void` return `null`.

If you don't explicitly have any return statement, the result of the last expression in your method is returned.

You can look at the bytecode... even if you declare a return type, you don't actually need to return anything as Groovy will, by default, return null:

```
// returns null
String callMe() { }

static void main(args) {
    def x = callMe()
    assert x == null
    println "OK!"
}
```

Because Spock will *assert* anything in the `then` block which is not a simple assignment, you need to avoid doing anything other than boolean assertions in the `then` block. Even assigning a variable, though allowed, should be avoided... It's hard to keep tests clean and clear, and by adhering to these guidelines will really work for you in the long run, not against you.

So, the correct way to write the assertion you want is to make your method return a boolean:

```
boolean hasHeaderText(String expectedText) {
    header.text() == expectedText
}
```

And use it in the `then` block:

```
then: 'The header has the expected text #expectedText'
hasHeaderText expectedText
```

Looks pretty good if you ask me.

**EDIT**

I've noticed that Groovy/Spock actually will **not** assert the result of a *normal* void method even in the `then` block... What's probably going on here is that you don't have a *normal* void method, you seem to be calling a dynamic method of `CollectionsPage` (I guess that's Geb's magic in play), which means that, probably, the Spock AST Transformer does not have the opportunity to check the signature of the method you're calling, so it correctly assumes it must assert the result... at least that's what it looks like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm aware of the things you wrote, especially the part in 'edit' notes. Indeed void method should not be evaluated as assert in spock's then block. Page's method is declared normal way, but that's my assumption as well, that Geb does some AST magic with it and thus breaks the contract. Using booleans with `expectedText` outside of the method is far from what I would like to achieve. Power assert elaborated failure messages are lost (think about comparing two maps for example) and text has to be repeated each time the method is used (DRY). I consider this to be a Geb bug

Answer (score 3):

@Renato is correct in the edited part of his response -  your call to a void method gets asserted by Spock because it's a dynamic call and Spock isn't able to figure out that you are calling a void method and eagerly asserts the call. If you changed your code to:

```
class NavigationSpec extends GebSpec {

    def 'Collections page has a right header'() {
        when:
            CollectionsPage collectionsPage = to CollectionsPage

        then:
            collectionsPage.hasHeaderText('Collections')
    }

}
```

then it won't get asserted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was pretty sure that this is because of some dynamic nature of the call. Oddly I didn't catch it works well if invoked directly on the owning object. By the way, which answer I should accept now? @Renato was first while yours gives more details :)

Comment: Probably @Renato deserves an accept as his response was the first correct one. :)

Comment: You're too humble. @Renato response was just a generic confirmation of my own assumptions that it is 'some dynamic magic' but there were neither any details provided of what's going on nor a solution. Thus, I'm accepting yours. I hope he doesn't mind...

Comment: That's fine by me :)

Comment: in case you're still waiting 1 year later, it's fine by me if you accept @erdi answer :)